# Is the below a legal python for loop ? Is there any documentation showing multiple iterators?

Tags: python

```py
def zipdir(dirpath):
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(dirpath):
        print("adding files in %s  " % (foldername))
        zf.write(foldername)
        for filename in filenames:
            zf.write(os.path.join(foldername,filename))
```

Comment: If a question isn't Raspberry Pi specific there is invariably a better site at which to ask the question.

Comment: Per previous comments, this is a non-Pi specific programming problem which would be better asked on either [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or possibly [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the `for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(dirpath):` line, yes thats allowed. You do the same thing to iterate over dictionaries via the `for key, value in {"key": "Value"}.items()` style.

If you mean the `for filename in filenames:`

Yes, sub loops using in-scope variables are allowed too.